# R, caret: does caret automatically create dummy variable for random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, r

I created a two class data set, `dat`. This data set only contains 25 variables. 24 are numeric and 1 is categorical (with 26 levels). The result of the auto-tuned model gives a `mtry` of 2, 14, 26, 38 and 50. So is this true that the caret created the dummy variable for the categorical variable? What other models does caret create dummy variable automatically?

Please see following example code.

```
pacman::p_load(R.utils, caret, doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(8, outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cl)
set.seed(2)
dat <- twoClassSim(48842, noiseVars = 10)# 25 variables.

dat = cbind(dat,data.frame(categorical = sample(LETTERS,nrow(dat),replace = T)))

fit_on <-  list(rs1 = 1:1300)
pred_on <- list(rs1 = 1330:10000)
indexFinal = 1:1000

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number=1,repeats=1,
                           classProbs = TRUE,summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                           index= fit_on, indexOut = pred_on,
                           indexFinal = indexFinal,
                           verboseIter = TRUE,
                           savePredictions = TRUE
)

model = train(Class ~ ., data = dat,  
              method = "rf",
              preProcess=c("center","scale"),
              trControl = fitControl,
              tuneLength = 5)

model

# mtry  ROC        Sens       Spec     
# 2    0.9166711  0.9298806  0.6778085
# 14    0.9237881  0.8851236  0.7645137
# 26    0.9177710  0.8746803  0.7770797
# 38    0.9132661  0.8689258  0.7753204
# 50    0.9093577  0.8687127  0.7728072
# there are only 25 variables.

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Yes, it does for some models. You can inspect which variables are used via model$coefnames.